# What is the meaning of "They have different entangled experiences" in this YouTube video?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-structure

What is the meaning of "They have different entangled experiences" in [this YouTube video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=QDQx524tByw&feature=emb_title) at 15:13? I looked up the meaning "entangled" in the dictionary. It shows "difficulties" but I don't think that applies in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker, Deepak Chopra, is famous for using precise scientific terminology incorrectly to describe his personal spiritual beliefs, making it sound like they have a scientific basis. This kind of talk is called "[pseudoscience](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pseudoscience)".

The word "entangled" is a scientific term from quantum physics. It's the adjective to describe two elementary particles that are in [quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement). But here Chopra is applying it to all living creatures, claiming we are all "entangled", and that dragonflies and butterflies are differently "entangled" because they can see all around themselves and with different types of light.

Comment: Your explanation of Chopra's argument in your last sentence is unclear to me.  He says, at 14:16 that we (humans) have "entangled experience[s]"; he then points out that our entangled experiences are particular to us. Insects, because they have a 360 degree field of vision, and because they can see ultraviolet light, have different entangled experiences than we do. I'm not sure where the connection to quantum mechanics is supposed to be in that.

Comment: @Juhasz There's no evidence in the quote or in the dozen or so seconds I listened to that make the connection to the quantum physics usage of "entanglement". Chopra is very well known for using quantum physics terminology like "entangled", "superposition", "field", "energy", "multiverse" and so on. Here's an example of his ["quantum woo"](https://youtu.be/QORg1u2Hbqk?t=38) and a few criticisms of it, including from a quantum physicist.